# how to keep app running in background to send timely notifications?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that will send a notification when user has moved more than 300 meters OR if not moved then after 2 hours.

However, the problem is that when I change time to 2 minutes, it appears to be working, but when I change time to 2 hours, it doesn't send me notification. May be the app goes on sleep mode? I don't know and even on distance change it doesn't send notification.

Here's my notification sending code, TrackMe.Java

```
package miniandroid.com.services;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

import miniandroid.com.activities.MainActivity;


public class TrackMeService extends Service {

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);       
          String mapfirst = prefs.getString("MapFirst", "");
          String mapsecond = prefs.getString("MapSecond", "");
          if (mapfirst != mapsecond){
              NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification mnotify = new Notification();
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                builder.setAutoCancel(false);
                builder.setTicker("This is important. You have unanswered questions in Smood App.");
                builder.setContentTitle("sMood");
                builder.setContentText("Please describe your mood at this location.");
                builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more);
                builder.setContentIntent(pending);
                builder.setOngoing(true);
                builder.setNumber(100);
                builder.build();
              mnotify= builder.getNotification();
              nm.notify(11,mnotify);
            SharedPreferences prefsy = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsy.edit();
            editor.putString("MapSecond", mapfirst);
            editor.commit();
          }
          else{

          }

            }
        }, 1);


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }


    public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    }


    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
    }


}
```

Here's the code for location service, LocationService.Java

```
package miniandroid.com.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import miniandroid.com.helpers.UserPreference;

public class LocationService extends Service {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    //private static final int TIME_DIFF = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 2 minutes
    private static final int TIME_DIFF = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2;  //2 hours
    private static final int DISTANCE_DIFF = 300;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        float distanceDelta = location.distanceTo(currentBestLocation);


        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TIME_DIFF;

        Log.d("MyLocationListener","onLocationChanged: Time Delta: "+ timeDelta+" Distance Delta: "+distanceDelta);

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {

            Log.d("MyLocationListener","onLocationChanged: Time Delta: is appropriate should show notification Time Delta: "+timeDelta);
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        }


        if(distanceDelta > DISTANCE_DIFF)
        {
            Log.d("MyLocationListener","onLocationChanged: Distance Delta: is appropriate should show notification Distance Delta: "+distanceDelta);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether two providers are the same
     */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }


    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
            if (isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                previousBestLocation = loc;
                startService(new Intent(LocationService.this,TrackMeService.class));
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

    }
}
```

The other class, location.java, is determining the location with lat-lng and also geocoding it to getAdress, however, I am only use lat-lng.
I set it to get the location after every two minutes and 10 meters changes. is that okay?

```
// How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    // The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 2 minutes
```

Any sorta help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the app still receiving notification when it not running, try to add **WAKE_LOCK** permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: It will keep the mobile phone on wake just for that app?

Comment: Yes so just add that if you really need

Comment: hi bro, I added that, but it doesn't makes my mobile phone screen go off, is it possible that it only uses cpu, the screen doesn't stay awake and it still sends me notification?

Comment: Try it bro :D actually I just use emulator for test and sreen doesnt turn off so I dont know about it. But I think it can receive notification although screen is off

Answer (score 0):

May be you should be using Foreground services. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Foreground services will not be killed by the OS.

Also please increase location update minimum time otherwise the app will discharge the battery even before those 2 hours ;) as I see you sending 0 as minTime and minDistance to requestLocationUpdates `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);`
.

Comment: oh, okay. let me digg in foreground services. Thank you for the tip, what could be the right time and distance to get the updates?